# Spring Role Base Authentication Microservice app

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices

In this picture I have tree structure and I want to give permission to any role above nodes.

[image]

Who can give me tips about this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are searching is "authorization" instead of "authentication". If you are using Spring, Spring Security is here to help you with your security needs. You can have roles and authorities to help you define what the user can access or do.

Using spring security, you can secure the endpoints using annotations like

```
@PreAuthorize(“hasAuthority('READ_AUTHORITY')")
```

or

```
@PreAuthorize(“hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

Comment: thanks , but i have 500 pages in tree , but should i use @PreAuthorize() on all pages?

Comment: you can add @PreAuthorize on controller level as well. This will authorize all the requests that are directed to the controller.